# Iterate JSON keys in PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to iterate the keys of JSON:

```
{
 "rates":
 {
  "AED":4.089781,
  "AFN":85.578915,
  "ALL":121.871136
 }
}
```

like:

```
key[0] = AED
key[1] = AFN .... and so on..
```

Or in a foreach loop

How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: [`array_keys(json_decode($ratesJson, true)['rates'])`](https://3v4l.org/rP1JQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in combination with 
[forEach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$j = json_decode('{
    "rates": {
        "AED":4.089781,
        "AFN":85.578915,
        "ALL":121.871136
    }}
');

foreach($j->rates as $key => $tmp) {
  echo $key . PHP_EOL;
}
# AED AFN ALL
```